# Cannot get bean from flowScope

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have a problem with my bean saved in flowScope, it doesn't recognize it-i receive null in my service class function, what could be the problem?

And I ask this because with other beans it works. I copy the code for the beans that would work and I saw that in the moment I change the name of the bean-instead of result="flowScope.a"-wich worked fine to result="flowScope.b" it doesn't work anymore(nullPointerException).

Please someone knows what could be the problem?I have to finish this project in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
  I forgot to change the name of the formObjectName(I was using formAction pattern)